# Checking for links in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code, where I have link in menu and submenu.
I have tried to write script and check if this "li" has submenu, this link don't work, but if "li" don't have submenu this link must move to its href.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".name ul li a", function (e) {
  if ($(this).next("ul")) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
         $(this).next("ul").show();
         $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
     }
     else {
         $(this).next("ul").hide();
         $(this).parent().addClass("active");
     }
   }
  else {
    $(this).css( "color", "yellow" );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "name">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">text A</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">text A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">text B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text B</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
  <li><a href="#">text A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">text A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">text B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text B</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But now all link in menu don't work.
Please tell me, where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` will always be truthy because `$(this).next("ul")` will always create an object even if no selector match is found.

`if(Object)` is always truthy

You need to check the `length` of matching selectors in the jQuery object

Change

```
if ($(this).next("ul")) {
```

To

```
if ($(this).next("ul").length) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do return true; instead of

```
  $(this).css( "color", "yellow" );
```

Return true keeps normal browser behavior (in this case follow the link). Return false cancels default browser behavior :)

Comment: no need to return anything ... the link will be followed when default isn't prevented

Comment: From my knowing returning true or false is a good habbit. preventDefault() is not working on all browsers (Maybe it was a case in older versions of jquery)

Comment: `preventDefault` works across all browsers and has for a very very long time. In fact it has been in jQuery library since version 1.0  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/